# Perl XOR escape string that contains "^"

Tags: perl, escaping, xor

How can I escape a "^" character when doing a bitwise XOR in Perl? My script is ok but when I input a string like `.1M80P]/)S@*>RQF^RM< \n` then the output gets messed up:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$key = pack("H*","3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd");

print "Enter string to decode: ";
$str=<STDIN>;chomp $str; $str =~s/\\(.)/$1/g;
$dec = decode($str);
print "Decoded string value: $dec\n";

sub decode{
    @subvar=@_;
    my $sqlstr = $subvar[0];
    $cipher = unpack("u", $sqlstr);
    $plain = $cipher^$key;
    return substr($plain, 0, length($cipher));
}
```

Output:

```
Enter string to decode: .1M80P]/)S@*>RQF^RM< \n
Decoded string value: zen94==tuvosÊ×
```

What is weird, the following string `,\=_\\^M;+ D1F$U@7L\n` works ok and decodes as `KL@OU4books!` but again `.;H ^F8B8EQ">SA^BDL8 \n` doesn't work as expected and gives back `R3@coldfusioÆ`

Here is the cleaned code by ikegami (same results though):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub deliteral {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
   die "Unrecognised escape \\$1\n" if $s =~ /\\[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
   $s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
   return $s;   
}

sub uudecode {
   return unpack 'u', $_[0];
}

sub decode {
   my ($key, $cipher) = @_;
   return substr($cipher^$key, 0, length($cipher)); # XXX
}

my $key = pack('H*', '3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd');

print "Enter string to decode: ";
chomp( my $coded = <STDIN> );

my $cipher = uudecode(deliteral($coded));
my $plain = decode($key, $cipher);
print("Plain text: $plain\n");
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't work when the plain text is longer than the key.

Comment: Not really, this works: `,6\\\=/S,G\!PQF?SQF5\n` decodes as `gt16.50otroX`

Comment: How is `gt16.50otroX` longer than the key?

Comment: You're right, is not. Maybe the problem is with the length?

Comment: "Unknown paste ID, it may have expired or been deleted!" Ooops, sorry, I deleted your last post.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't say how it was encoded. I did some work for you, though. [This](http://www.paste.to/MjU3MTk=) handles your preprocessing better (`$str =~s/\\(.)/$1/g;` wasn't quite right) and fixes your scoping errors.

Comment: (I accidentally deleted the code I posted. I had to retype it all.  Oops!)

Comment: uuencoding produces newline-ended ASCII characters. Your SQL client is escaping the newlines to `\n`, and you were converting those to `n` instead of newlines.

Comment: Thank you for the prettier code, but same problem...this is Coldfusion 6 encryption method I try to duplicate in Perl anf the encoded strings are real encoded strings. And I think you're right, nit `^` is the problem as I thought, anything upto 12 chars decodes ok but longer does not...Any idea how to continue the decoding of the string upto the last character in the string eve if it's 13 or 15 characters length?

Comment: I know, I didn't fix your `decode`. Like I said, we can't if you don't tell us how the string was encoded. I fixed the rest of your code.

Comment: hum, interesting. The cipher text for `R3@coldfusion` is 14 bytes long, but the password is only 13 bytes long.

Comment: Yeah, but I think a character is missing there in the "R3@coldfusion"

Comment: Come on man, give me reliable data! Encrypt a 13 char string and give me both the plain text and the coded text

Comment: Ok, here it is: `-\#8%-SM+"Q$[2C4?_SP  \n` this should return `1234567890123` is 13 characters.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24882/discussion-between-xtmtrx-and-ikegami)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution, thanks to ikegami help:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub deliteral {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
   die "Unrecognised escape \\$1\n" if $s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/;   $s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
   return $s;   
}

sub uudecode {
   return unpack 'u', $_[0];
}

sub decode {
   my ($key, $cipher) = @_;
   return substr($cipher^$key, 0, length($cipher)); # XXX
}

my $key = pack('H*', '3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b33332fc96ff7b');

print "Enter string to decode: ";
chomp( my $coded = <STDIN> );

my $cipher = uudecode(deliteral($coded));
my $plain = decode($key, $cipher);
print("Plain text: $plain\n");
```

The problem was with the length of the KEY.